# How to send email as HTML via deliver_now and not have a separate class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm curious if I can send the following as HTML email without having to make it its own class:

```
  def self.hourly
    puts "here is hourly"
    page_views=PageView.where('created_at > ?',Time.now-1.hour)
    str=ActionView::Base.new(
        Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"]).render(
        :partial => 'stats/page_views',
        :locals => { page_views: page_views })
    ActionMailer::Base.mail(from: 'from@domain.com', to: 'jon@domain.com', subject: "Welcome to My Awesome Site", body: str).deliver_now

  end
```

It currently gets sent as text.

### Edit

I adjusted to this, but I"m getting this following template error:

```
ActionMailer::Base.mail(from: 'from@domain.io', to: 'jon@jon.com', subject: "Welcome to My Awesome Site") do |format|
   format.html { render html: "<h1>Hey there</h1>".html_safe }
 end.deliver_now
```

I get:

```
[1] pry(main)> MyStats.hourly
here is hourly

ActionMailer::Base#mail: processed outbound mail in 15.1ms
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template action_mailer/base/mail with "mailer". Searched in:
  * "action_mailer/base"
from /Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:916:in `each_template'
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs for [`ActionMailer::Base.mail`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail):

> You can even render plain text directly without using a template:

```
mail(to: 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net') do |format|
  format.text { render plain: "Hello Mikel!" }
  format.html { render html: "<h1>Hello Mikel!</h1>".html_safe }
end
```

So I believe you could do something like this in your example:

```
ActionMailer::Base.mail(from: 'from@domain.com', to: 'jon@domain.com', subject: "Welcome to My Awesome Site") do |format|
  format.html { render html: str.html_safe }
end.deliver_now
```

Comment: thx - so I had tried something similar but have been getting the error msg in the above edit.  I thought this was going to really simple but alas.